# Distinguishing between f# overloaded functions with optional parameters

Tags: f#

F# allows overloaded functions to differ only by an optional parameter, for example:

```
type MyClass() = 
    member this.func(a: string, b:string) = "func(a,b)"
    member this.func(a: string, ?b:string) = "func(a,?b)"
```

How would you call the first function?

Comment: you can just rename second parameter in any function: `type MyClass() = 
    member this.func(a: string, b:string) = "func(a,b)"
    member this.func(a: string, ?c:string) = "func(a,?c)"

let test = MyClass()

let arg1 = "2"
let arg2 = "12"

test.func(arg1, b = arg2) |> printfn "%s" //func(a,b)
test.func(arg1, c = arg2) |> printfn "%s" //func(a,?c)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think there is a sensible way to call the first function if the two overloaded functions differ only by an optional parameter. As mentioned in the comments, using this is probably a poor design and you should rename the parameters.

As you probably noticed, when you try calling the function in an ordinary way using `MyClass().func("A","B")`, you get an error message complaining about the ambiguity:

> error FS0041: A unique overload for method 'func' could not be determined based on type information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed. Candidates: member MyClass.func : a:string * ?b:string -> string, member MyClass.func : a:string * b:string -> string

You can call the second overload explicitly in two ways (with or without `?b`) thanks to the fact that you can explicitly provide `Some`  value for an optional argument:

```
MyClass().func("A")
MyClass().func("A",?b=Some "B")
```

Out of curiosity, it turns out that you can call the first overload via a static member constraint. This is quite ugly and you probably shouldn't be doing this, but it calls the first overload:

```
let inline callFunc (o:^T) a b = 
  (^T : (member func : string * string -> string) (o, a, b)) 

callFunc (MyClass()) "A" "B"
```